# Big Theta (Θ) runtime of recursive functions

Tags: c++, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I'm having trouble trying to understand the runtime. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
int foo(int x) {
  if (x <= 0) return x; 
     cout << x;
     return foo (x-1);
}

void bar(int n) {
  if (n <= 0) return;
  cout << foo (n) << endl;
  bar (n-1);
  cout << n;
}

int main() {
 int n;
 cin >> n;
 bar(n);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise about what is giving you trouble?

Comment: I know that the base case for foo and bar would take 2.T(0) = 2 = Θ(1). But I don't understand how to formulate the recurrence relation for the recursive functions.

Comment: Plug in a number and paper trace?

Answer (score 0):

Foo is printing the number you passes and it will do x-- until is 0, if you pass 5 it will print 543210, so you can called it decrement n by 1 and print the result

Bar is doing the same without printing, only decrementing and calling foo

It is a 3 recursion level, try to use a small number and follow the flow, like 4

-Bar gets 4, the case base it is 0, 4 is greater than 0 so it will continue, it will call foo(4) (remenber that foo is a recursive call that will print 4 to 0 => 43210, decrementing the number by 1 each time)
-And bar gets called again, this time with n-1 = 4 -1 = 3, with the value 3, it will call foo(3) and the same

When you meet the case base in bar, n == 0 you will stop calling anothers functions and this function will get the value returned, you can print on screnn but it doesnt mean that the function ends, it was waiting for the other values to return, when it returns it prints the n that called it, so it will be 1234, that is it that the values 1, 2, 3 and 4 are the values that enter bars one at a time and prints the value of the result of foo (for 4,3,2,1) because it is what you get

```
int foo(int x) { //Decrementing by one and printing the value
  // If x reaches 0 exit (you need an exit in a recursion)
  if (x <= 0) return x; 
  // Print the value x (the first time x will be the n, the second n-1)
  cout << x;
  // Call the same function in we are but with x-1 value
  return foo (x-1);
}
// It will produce foo(4)=>foo(3)=>foo(2)=>foo(1) and foo(0)
// foo(0) will break the recursion and finish here (only prints)

 // It is where main calls and enters n is the value you type
 void bar(int n) {
   // Case base to break recursion when it reaches 0
   if (n <= 0) return;
   // Here is the code that prints the line that foo will make
   cout << foo (n) << endl;
   // Here you will call the same function but with n-1, like foo does
   bar (n-1);
   // When all the recursion above is over you will get here
   // In the stack you will have done n calls into here with n-x
   // So every one will print the value of n that in the paremeter 
   // when the call was make 
   cout << n;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand the program much better now :) So, is the big theta runtime the summation of i=0 to n of i? Θ(n^2)? Is there a better way to think of the runtime?

Comment: I think it is n+n² but i an not completely sure so i didnt post anything about it